# Segmentation Core dumped

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

```
| |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
|0| | | | | | | | | | |
|1| | | | | | | | | | |
|2| | | | | | | | | | |
|3| | | | | | | | | | |
|4| | | | | | | | | | |
|5| | | | | | | | | | |
|6| | | | | | | | | | |
|7| | | | | | | | | | |
|8| | | | | | | | | | |
|9| | | | | | | | | | |
```

I am trying to make a grid that looks like this. I currently keep getting Segmentation Fault Core dumped whenever I try to run the executable. The compiler is also not showing any errors. I am not sure how to print the numbers inside the grid either. Below is the code I currently have (just a part of the whole assignment). Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Player * player)
{
    /* TODO */
    int i,j;
    char grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2];
    for(i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < BOARD_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2] = '|';
            printf("%c", grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2]);
            printf("%s", EMPTY_OUTPUT);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

The BOARD_HEIGHT and BOARD_WIDTH are variables defined in a header file.

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include "helpers.h"
#include "player.h"

#define BOARD_WIDTH 10
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 10

typedef enum cell
{
    EMPTY,
    BLOCKED,
    PLAYER
} Cell;

#define EMPTY_OUTPUT " "
#define BLOCKED_OUTPUT "*"

Cell BOARD_1[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
Cell BOARD_2[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];

typedef enum playerMove
{
    PLAYER_MOVED,
    CELL_BLOCKED,
    OUTSIDE_BOUNDS
} PlayerMove;


void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);

void loadBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH],
               Cell boardToLoad[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);

Boolean placePlayer(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Position position);

PlayerMove movePlayerForward(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH],
                         Player * player);

void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Player * player);

#endif
```

this second part is in the header file.

The full code can be found here [a1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oHqGHlyZsASmdVWGpxR1FIVkU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you show the complete code?

Comment: `grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @aschepler, it's not. OP needs to show more code. The Seg fault is happening elsewhere.

Comment: even after defining grid[12][12] it still presents me with the same error

Comment: BTW The contents of the `board` are not used. I think `grid` is not necessary.

Comment: Can you just link me to the complete code? @GeraldLim

Comment: You are missing the part of the code that outputs the numbers, and you are not using the passed in Board array, but are instead using an uninitialized grid array. There is no need to use the grid array, nor store the '|' character in the array at all, just print out the lines as needed, but do not store them.

Final and most important point, you should be indexing into the array using i and j, not constants like BOARD_HEIGHT and BOARD_WIDTH, because as written you are outputting grid[12][12] 144 times.

Comment: You are missing players.h and helper.h. You should reduce your question to a minimal sized code fragment that compiles and reproduces the issue. When I run your code, after adding in some missing code (that I had to make up), it runs without a seg fault. That demonstrates the need to provide a complete example that compiles on its own, and demonstrates the issue. When we have to add our own code, it usually just works. :)

Comment: @narusin yep, here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oHqGHlyZsASmdVWGpxR1FIVkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are 22 rows and columns in your example output. A 12x12 grid isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @ScottK thanks for your advice, I have edited the post so you can find the rest of my files at that link. I'm not sure how to approach your method, can you help me clarify?

Comment: when asking a question, do NOT post links to the code, post the code right in the question.  Those snippets of  posted code do not compile.  Post code that is short, cleanly compiles, and still exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is on the line where you index grid beyond the end of the array:

```
grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2] = '|'; // Bug
```

This line writes beyond the end of the grid array defined locally as:

```
char grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2];
```

Note that the valid indexes into grid[][] go from 0 to BOARD_HEIGHT+1, and 0 to BOARD_WIDTH+1. Your code is accessible one past this in both dimensions.

This results in corrupting the stack, so when the displayBoard function returns, it has corrupted the stack and you get a segmentation fault. Removing this line eliminates the seg fault, but the code still needs work for function correctly.

You should reference the board array, and use indexes i and j, not hardcoded constants.

Here is a working version where I index into the board array, store the current cell value in currentCell, then display it based on a switch statement. This produces the following output given an empty board filled with zeroes:

```
scott> gcc -g -ogeraldTest -O0 board.c
scott> geraldTest 
| |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
|0| | | | | | | | | | |
|1| | | | | | | | | | |
|2| | | | | | | | | | |
|3| | | | | | | | | | |
|4| | | | | | | | | | |
|5| | | | | | | | | | |
|6| | | | | | | | | | |
|7| | | | | | | | | | |
|8| | | | | | | | | | |
|9| | | | | | | | | | |
```

Here is the code for main() and printBoard, both in board.c. Note that printBoard is passed the board by value, but it would be better to pass it by reference.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "board.h"

    void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Player * player)
    {
        int i,j;

        // First display the header at the top.
        printf("| |");
        for(j=0; j<BOARD_WIDTH;j++)
           printf("%d|",j);
        printf("\n");

        for(i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++)
        {
         // Display each row number
         printf("|%d|",i);

        for(j = 0; j < BOARD_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            // Bug: grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2] = '|';
            Cell currentCell = board[i][j];

            switch(currentCell) {
               case BLOCKED:
                  printf("%s",BLOCKED_OUTPUT);
                  break;
               case PLAYER:
                  printf("P");
                  break;
               default:
                  printf("%s",EMPTY_OUTPUT);
                  break;
            }
            printf("|");

            // This code is wrong
            // printf("%c|", grid[BOARD_HEIGHT + 2][BOARD_WIDTH + 2]);
            // printf("%s", EMPTY_OUTPUT);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      Cell myBoard[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH] = {0};
      Player bob = 0;

      displayBoard(myBoard, &bob);
    }
```

I took your board.h and defined the missing types in order to get it to compile. You can likely just use your own headers as is.

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

// #include "helpers.h"
// #include "player.h"

#define BOARD_WIDTH 10
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 10

typedef int  Boolean; // Added
typedef int  Player;  // Added
typedef struct {      // Added
          int row;
          int col;
        } Position;

typedef enum cell
{
    EMPTY,
    BLOCKED,
    PLAYER
} Cell;

#define EMPTY_OUTPUT " "
#define BLOCKED_OUTPUT "*"

Cell BOARD_1[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
Cell BOARD_2[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];

typedef enum playerMove
{
    PLAYER_MOVED,
    CELL_BLOCKED,
    OUTSIDE_BOUNDS
} PlayerMove;


void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);

void loadBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH],
               Cell boardToLoad[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);

Boolean placePlayer(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Position position);

PlayerMove movePlayerForward(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH],
                         Player * player);

void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Player * player);
#endif
```

Comment: For future reference, this needn't [and _shouldn't_] be a separate answer. Since you already posted one, editing your old answer and appending [the text in] this one would have been the way to go. Answers often start out like your first one, then may be edited several times [adding lots of text]. Multiple answers from the same responder is generally frowned upon unless there is an exceptional reason (e.g. The answer you want to give will exceed the 30,000 char limit on an answer). That's why, when you tried to add the 2nd answer, you got a reminder and a "are you sure you want to do this?".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip @CraigEstey, I appended one answer to the other, and deleted the second. I am new to StackOverflow, so appreciate the advice. Thanks.